# How to add jsonarray response in linear layout?

Tags: java, android

I am getting a json response in which i am getting jsonObject and jsonArray. I successfully set values for jsonObject but for JsonArray i have two values for each as que ans ans. for example:

```
 "question": [
            {
                "ans": "test",
                "que": "What is your name"
            },
            {
                "ans": "25-30",
                "que": "Age"
            }
        ]
```

this is jsonarray in jsonObject. Now i want to set que and ans in textbox. Note that number of questions are not fixed, they can be 12 or more or less depends on API.

My question is how to set this questions in layout inflater or anything like that?
thanks in advance :)

Comment: So, you want to show that info in a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use inflation like this: Keep one item.xml which will hold 2 TextViews (or EditText as per your need.)

item.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/item_row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/que"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ans"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now in your code:

You would need to inflate that item.xml in a loop for as many items you get in your JSONArray. So firstly parse JSONArray and get a ArrayList of Question, Answer pair:

```
ArrayList<String[]> myArr = new ArrayList<String[]>();
for (int i=0; i < myJSONArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject j = myJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String[] t = {j.getString("que"),j.getString("ans")};
    myArr.add[t];
}
```

Pass this to your activity.

Now you would need to iterate through the ArrayList and inflate your layout, populate TextViews with values in map, and add the inflated view in parent layout:

```
RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mylayout);  //this will be your container layout
for (int i = 0; i < secQAArr.size(); i++){

    View item = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item, null);
    TextView tQue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que);
    que.seText(secQAArr.get(i)[0]);
    TextView tAns = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans);
    que.seText(secQAArr.get(i)[1]);
    container.addView(item);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

**activity_main.xml**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnrQuestionContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**question.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtQuestion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAnswer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private LinearLayout lnrQuestionContainer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lnrQuestionContainer =(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lnrQuestionContainer);

        try{
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{\"question\":[{\"ans\":\"test\",\"que\":\"What is your name\"},{\"ans\":\"25-30\",\"que\":\"Age\"}]}");
            JSONArray questionJsonArray =  jsonObject.getJSONArray("question");

            for(int i=0;i<questionJsonArray.length();i++){
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.question,null);
                TextView txtQuestion = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtQuestion);
                TextView txtAnswer = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtAnswer);

                txtQuestion.setText("Question "+(i+1)+" : "+questionJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("que"));
                txtAnswer.setText("Answer "+(i+1)+" : "+questionJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("ans"));
                lnrQuestionContainer.addView(view);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am struggling on the adding linear layout dynamically ,having its row . within the ListView.can you please help me??